# Laravel 5 forgotten password email template condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the Laravel 5 built in user stuff with [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) for user roles and permissions. I have two roles set up which are administrators and users. Basically what I want to do is have two different forgotten password email templates - one for users and one for administrators. So when a user enters their email address to get the reset link emailed to them I need to check what sort of user they are first and then send them the right template. I don't want to have to do any sort of hacky stuff in the standard email template their must be a way to do this in the controller or something surely? Anyone know how I would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably prompt them to enter their email and when they submit you can grab it in the controller:

```
public function forgot()
{
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

    if($user->type == 'admin') {
        // logic to email admin with admin template
    } else {
        // logic to email user with user template 
    }

    // redirect to success page letting user know the email was sent
    return View::make('someview');
}
```

Or better yet, just pass the user type to an email service that handles the emailing:

```
public function forgot()
{
   $email = Input::get('email');
   $user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

   $emailService->sendForgotForType($user->type);

   // redirect to success page letting user know the email was sent
   return View::make('someview');
}
```

**If you are using Laravel 5's built in User Management:**

To override the default template used you would need to manually set the `$emailView` in the `PasswordBroker.php` by writing a new class that extends `PasswordBroker`.

For example, comment out `'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider'` in config/app.php

Then create an extension class:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword;

class MyPasswordBroker extends PasswordBroker {

    // override 
    public function emailResetLink(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token, Closure $callback = null)
    {
        // Override Logic to email reset link function perhaps using the example above?
    }
}
```

Then you would need to bind your new `MyPasswordBroker` class to `AppServiceProvider` at `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in the register method (below found online):

```
$this->app->bind('App\Model\PasswordBroker', function($app) {
    $key = $app['config']['app.key'];
    $userToken = new \App\Model\NewUserToken; 
    $tokens = new \App\Repository\NewTokenRepository($key,$userToken);
    $user = new \App\Model\NewUser;
    $view = $app['config']['auth.password.email'];
    return new \App\Model\PasswordBroker($tokens, $users, $app['mailer'], $view);
});
```

Definitely moderately advanced stuff, if you can handle it - great.  Otherwise I would possibly look into using an authentication package with built in features you need.

Comment: But where is the controller that handles this?

Comment: Well, you'd need to create the route and controller to do this. entrust doesn't have everything built in.  It sounds like you may need to read up on some Laravel foo a bit?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I think you've misunderstood the question a bit. The forgotten password stuff isn't anything to do with entrust it's the built in user stuff that laravel comes with. Say for example I wasn't using entrust and I just wanted to pick a template at random from one of two when a user resets their password, where would I put the logic to do that is what I'm asking really.